# "Share your Developer Story" links lead to 404 pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story, hyperlinks

On the right-hand side of my Developer Story, I see the following:

[image]

Both links (https://stackoverflow.com/story/YehudaShapira and https://stackoverflow.com/cv/YehudaShapira) lead to 404 pages, even though my story is set to Public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fixed!

This was a casing issue in the database from the imports - we should have lower-cased the slugs when they came in and goofed it. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the report.